# Need message located above submit button to change depending on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to get this code working for about an hour in at work and have been struggling to find the reason for it not functioning as I'm intending. I'm hoping maybe another set of eyes can liven up my day.

```
jQuery('select[name="form[State]"]').change(function() {
    if ( ['CT','GA','NY','WA','AK','DC','MA','MT','NH','VT','WV'].indexOf(jQuery(this).val()) >= 0) {
        jQuery('.select-message').html('Unfortunately at this time, due to state regulation, we are unable to present a loan offer to you while you reside in your state. We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused');
    } else if ( jQuery(this).val() == 'IL') {
        jQuery('.select-message').html('The Direct Lender licensed in your state offers an open ended revolving credit plan. Please click here to acknowledge and proceed.');
    } else if ( ['WI','MO','NM'].indexOf(jQuery(this).val()) >= 0) {
        jQuery('.select-message').html('The Direct Lender licensed in your state offers an installment loan. Please click here to acknowledge and proceed.');
    } else if ( jQuery(this).val() == 'TX') {
        jQuery('.select-message').html('A Credit Service Organization licensed in your state will attempt to obtain an installment loan on your behalf. Please click here to acknowledge and proceed.');
    } else {
        jQuery('.select-message').html('');
    }
});
```

Link: https://www.snappypaydayloans.com/

Comment: Your logic looks right. Could you post the html as well to figure out what might be the issue ?

Comment: If you go to the link at the bottom of the question it's the form right at the top of the page.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine.  I placed your code in the console and when I change the state to "Texas", I see "A Credit Service Organization licensed in your state will attempt to obtain an installment loan on your behalf. Please click here to acknowledge and proceed."

Having said that, its black text on very dark gray.  It is hard to see.  Also, the form changes because the HTML in the select-message gets very large, but that should be easy to fix.

Comment: That's wierd, maybe our network is caching snappypaydayloans.com? You checked it on the website I linked? When I visit the website it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`, because your event handler is added before your markup is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('select[name="form[State]"]').change(function() {
        //your function 
    });
});
```

Another way is to use `on()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('change', 'select[name="form[State]"]', function() {
        //your function 
    });
});
```

Comment: I just added it and it still seems to not be working.

Comment: @StephenSabatini can you try the my second suggestion?

Comment: Nice - is working. I think the first one didn't work because I forgot to push it up in dreamweaver and just saved. Long day - thank you so much!

Comment: @StephenSabatini Also Steve's suggestion is a good one. and you can simply use `this.value` instead of `jQuery(this).val()` for making the code look more compact.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Internet Explorer <= 8, `indexOf` does not work on arrays.  Use [jQuery.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead.

So change your first if statement to:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), ['CT','GA','NY','WA','AK','DC','MA','MT','NH','VT','WV']) > -1)
```

Comment: We're starting to discontinue support for IE8 anyways, but that's not the problem because I'm using the latest version of Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7.